# how to use split and replace in same expression in liquid json transformation?

Tags: json, transform, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

input string -

```
{"testData":"jack%2C LLC,ville%2C LLC,Nav LLC,50 New Hope%2C LLC,"}
```

expected output

```
{"output":"<Value>jack, LLC</Value><Value>ville, LLC</Value><Value>Nav LLC</Value><Value>50 New Hope, LLC</Value>"}
```

for conversion using this -

%2C is converted to , comma after converting into value tags so that it does not interfare with the delimiter comma.

I tried like below expression

```
{% 
       "output": "<Value>{{ demo | Split: ',' | Last   }}</Value>",

%}
```

But need to use replace first to replace `%2C` to `,`  and then use `split` string using `,` and seperate all available values and use `<Value>` tag.

expected output is  -

```
   {"output":"<Value>jack, LLC</Value><Value>ville, LLC</Value><Value>Nav LLC</Value><Value>50 New Hope, LLC</Value>"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can use the liquid template as below:

```
{% assign arr = content.testData | Split: "," %}
{
    "output": "{% for item in arr  %}<value>{{item | Replace: "%2C", ","}}</value>{% endfor %}"
}
```

Hope it helps~