# How to use foreach and append string in liquid json transformation

Tags: json, azure, transform, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

Original Input json -

```
{
 "demo" : "a12,b45,c78" ,
 "status" :  "1" 
}
```

Expected output is xml

```
<demo>
<Value>a12</Value>
<Value>b45</Value>
<Value>c78</Value>
</demo>
<status>done</status>
```

I will first create a json and then use @xml() in logic app to convert this into xml tried like below which works fine but its hardcoded how to use foreach for dynamic.

```
{
 {% if content.status == "1" %}
 "status" : "done"
 {% elsif content.status == "2" %} 
      "status" : "done"
 {% endif %}
"demo": {"Value":["a12","b45","c78"]}
}
```

for demo c# code will be like -

```
 string a = "a12,b45,c78";

            var aa = a.Split(',').ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement, we can use some actions in logic app to get `"a12,b45,c78"` and then split them to array, then convert them from json to xml. But I think this solution is too complicated, we may need to do many operations in logic app. So in your logic app, you can do what you have done before and get the result `<demo>a12,b45,c78</demo>`. Then use xslt map to transform ths xml to the format which you want. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** I do the same operation as you mentioned in your question.
[image]

**2.** We need to create a xslt template as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="demo/text()" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                </Value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**3.** Save the xslt template as the type of `.xslt` and upload it to the Map of your integration account. When you do the upload, please choose "Map type" as "XSLT 2.0".

**4.** Use Transform XML action to do the transform (choose the map which you uploaded above).
[image]

**5.** After that, we can get the result which you want.
[image]

**Update:**

You can use the liquid template as below:

```
{% assign arr = content.demo | Split: "," %}
{
    {% if content.status == "1" %}
        "status": "done",
    {% else %}
        "status": "undone",
    {% endif %}
    "demo": {
        "Value":[
            {% for item in arr  %}
                "{{item}}",
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    }
}
```

Then get the json data which you want:

```
{
  "status": "done",
  "demo": {
    "Value": [
      "a12",
      "b45",
      "c78"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm doing mapping into .liquid file is there any way to write expression into liquid ? 
I can do conversion to xml later in compose using `xml()` 

need to get this using liquid -

`{
"demo": {"Value":["a12","b45","c78"]}
}`

Comment: updated question with my liquid which works fine for if else

Comment: or pls guide me for that complex logic do it within liquid only using foreach and assign array and split operations?

Comment: Hi @Neo I will do some test and update my answer later.

Comment: @Neo I have updated my answer, please check if it can meet your requirement. By the way, if you want to transform the result json data to xml by "xml()" method in logic app. You may need to add a "<root> </root>" element outside of the json data.

Comment: @Neo You are welcome. If it works fine, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60546659/how-to-use-split-and-replace-in-same-expression-in-liquid-json-transformation

Comment: Thanks @Neo. I will check the post and so some research, but maybe I will reply you next week because I will be off work after a few moment.

Comment: Oh sure if possible just comment with some clue I will try